# Avoiding tilt in imagemagic montage

Tags: image-processing, imagemagick, montage

I use this command to generate montage:

> montage *.jpg -thumbnail 600x600 -set
>   caption %t -background grey40
>   -pointsize 16 -density 188x188 +polaroid -resize 50%  -background white -geometry +1+1 -tile 4x4 -title
>   "My Collection" polaroid_t.jpg

The images in the montage get tilted to either left or side. How can I have them strait?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [fine manual](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php?#polaroid):

> Use +polaroid to rotate the image at a random angle between -15 and +15 degrees.

I think you want `-polaroid 0` instead of `+polaroid`.